# Limiting mysql log file size

Tags: mysql, database, logging, logfile

I have a mysql log file that regularly goes over 30gb, this sucks when you realise that your server is full because of this file. I need a simple solution to limit this file to about 1gb, i don't need logs that run that long, and i'd rather avoid this problem in the future.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to `InnoDB`? If so, read [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/07/09/how-to-change-innodb_log_file_size-safely/) how to change `innodb_log_file_size` safely.

Comment: You can use [mysql-log-rotate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html) for this

Comment: @njk: The InnoDB log file does not increase in size.

Comment: Which file are you referring to? InnoDB transaction log (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1)? Binary log? Relay log? Slow Log? Error Log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify it in the my.cnf file, backup your current my.cnf file (always recommended), stop slave, stop the MySQL server and place the following option:

```
   # relay log restrictions
   relay-log-space-limit=15G
```

Then save and quit the file and start MySQL. Unless you configured differently, MySQL will automatically start the slave thread.

Comment: Thanks i'll attempt that when i can restart the server and see if it works.